# HTML encoding for spanish, working locally but not on the server

Tags: php, html, encoding, utf-8, gettext

I am adding spanish as a language and I'm having problems with the encoding.

All the spanish characters work perfectly locally (this makes it harder to debug):

[image]

But on the server they look this way:

[image]

I'm pretty puzzled, you can see the beta version [here](http://beta.getfinn.com/).

My doctype and charset are the following:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
...
```

Which should be correct as far as I understand.

I am using gettext for translations.

I checked and the declared encoding of the .po file is UTF-8.

I also set `bind_textdomain_codeset` to UTF-8.

I'm not sure where the problem is actually relying.

Comment: What's the HTTP `Content-Type` header look like?

Comment: @deceze https://gist.github.com/trufa/7751639

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your server is set to serve pages with this Content-Type header:

```
Content-Type:text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
```

You need to tell it to serve them as `charset=utf-8` instead. You can do this in PHP too:

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
```

Comment: Awesome, it works perfect! but I don't understand where the problem is  exactly, why is the server serving another charset?

Comment: Because its default is set differently than your local server. This has nothing to do with what charset you're actually sending, it's just a default line the server adds if you don't do it yourself.

Comment: @Trufa - The server will not waste resources reading your documents and trying to guess what their encoding is. You have to set it explicitly. (Furthermore, guessing would not work.)